# riak-admin reports node not running but REST API responds

Tags: riak

I have a 5 node Riak cluster running.  I ssh to node 1 and run 'riak-admin test' the output of which is "Node is not running!"..however the REST API responds (eg http://{localhst}:8098/stats returns JSON stats as expected) and I can run a client that hits the ProtoBuf endpoint ok too. I must be making a noob mistake but what? (yes, have tried sudo riak-admin test)

I'm running Riak in a docker container on Debian Jessie host and have established ssh session via docker  exec -i -t [container name} bash.  I have hit the HTTP endpoint with curl from the session.

Answer (score 0):

This, as you might expect, turns out to be environmental.  I have my five nodes running in five docker containers as per http://basho.com/riak-quick-start-with-docker/

Each time a container is recycled during a session of the host it is assigned the next ip address.  The riak instance in the container has it's address statically configured, hence if I recycle a container the actual IP and the static IP for riak do not match.

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered this when the hostname doesn't contain a ".", which is the case with docker's default hostnames. I always have to start my riak containers with `docker run --hostname riakN.docker`.